# jQuery: Find all DIVs containing specific elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to adjust the height of a div if certain conditions are true.
Specifically, I want to find any .element divs that contain a textarea and in which the error message div exists.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).find('textarea') && $(this).find('.error-message') ) {
        $(this).css('min-height', '80px');
    }   
});
```

Given this structure, only the middle div should get the extra height:

```
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div class="error-message"></div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Provided code is the actual solution. But you should check the length of finded child elements instead of actual result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.length` will be your friend here:

```js
$('.element').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('textarea').length && $(this).find('.error-message').length) {
    $(this).css('min-height', '80px');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div class="error-message"></div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

While you're finding the proper elements with your selectors, in order to test them in an `if` condition you'll want to use `.length` which returns the number of elements in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use chaining of :has selector here:

```
 $('.element:has(.error-message):has(textarea)').css('min-height', '80px');
```

```js
$('.element:has(.error-message):has(textarea)').css('min-height', '80px');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div class="error-message"></div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: It is really experimental stuff. I'd rather choose to not use it for more compatible code.

Comment: Note that using `:has` is also far slower than `.length`

Comment: @j08691 Slower regarding perf for sure but wins regarding readability imho

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the length of the error-message class like this:

```
var elem = $('.element');
if(elem.find('.error-message').length > 0) {
  // Code here
}
```